# If $X \sim N(0,I_m)$, what is a necessary and sufficient condition on $u_m > 0$ such that $\lim\sup_{m\to \infty} P(\|X\|^2 \ge u_m|X_1|) = 1$

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, measure-concentration, lower-bounds

Let $m$ be a large positive integer and $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_m) \sim N(0,I_m)$. I wish to show that the squared norm of $X$ is much much bigger than the absolute value of any of the $X_j$'s. For example, [one can show](https://mathoverflow.net/a/369322/78539) that$P(\|X\|^2 \ge \mathcal O(\sqrt{m})|X_1|) = 1-o(1)$. Recall that $o(1)$ is notation for any quantity which goes to $0$ in the sup-limit $m \to \infty$.

My goal is to improve the $\sqrt{m}$ to something much larger. To this end, let $(u_m)_m$ be a sequence of positive numbers.

> **Question.** What is a sufficient (and ideally, also necessary) condition on the growth of $u_m$ such that $P(\|X\|^2 \ge u_m |X_1|) = 1-o(1)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For real $u_m>0$, the probability in question is
$$p_m:=P(\|X\|^2\ge u_m|X_1|)=P\Big(\frac{|X_1|}{\|X\|^2/m}\le\frac m{u_m}\Big).$$
Passing to a subsequence, without loss of generality
$$\frac{u_m}m\to c\in[0,\infty]$$
(as $m\to\infty$). By the law of large numbers, $\|X\|^2/m\to1$ in probability. So, by [Slutsky's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem) ,
$$p_m\to p_\infty:=P(|X_1|\le1/c),$$
assuming $1/0:=\infty$ and $1/\infty:=0$. Thus, $p_m\to1$ iff $c=0$. That is, $P(\|X\|^2\ge u_m|X_1|)=1-o(1)$ iff  $u_m=o(m)$.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the nice answer!